# Python beautiful soup4- find_all returns "[]"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python `BS4` to scrape the https://skinup.gg website. I am trying to get the multiplier class, in order, from a website.

I tried to scrape the information by taking all the data from the div history class. However it just returns `[]` and I am stumped on how to get the multipliers.

I wonder if it is because the *div tag class values are constantly changing*. Which leads me to my second question: how do they have dynamic values in html tags? Is it done via `Javascript`?

Excuse my grammar.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

page = requests.g et("https://skinup.gg/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")


print(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'win'}))
```

Relevant website code:

```
<div class="history"><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">23:05</time>
  <span class="multiplier">2.19</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">23:04</time>
  <span class="multiplier">2.62</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">23:04</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.75</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">23:04</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.00</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">23:04</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.21</span>
</div><div style="">
  <time class="date">23:03</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.82</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">23:03</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.00</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">23:03</time>
  <span class="multiplier">2.91</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">23:02</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.01</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">23:02</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1184.44</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">23:01</time>
  <span class="multiplier">36.81</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">22:59</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.38</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">22:59</time>
  <span class="multiplier">2.42</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">22:59</time>
  <span class="multiplier">8.00</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">22:58</time>
  <span class="multiplier">3.42</span>
</div><div class="win" style="">
  <time class="date">22:57</time>
  <span class="multiplier">2.04</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">22:57</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.17</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">22:57</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.24</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">22:57</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.11</span>
</div><div class="lose" style="">
  <time class="date">22:56</time>
  <span class="multiplier">1.53</span>
</div>

                </div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use `requests` or `urllib` for this task. It's a js generated tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the website in question you will need to use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to get the data you want.

Comment: For the question it looks like the OP already knows that `find_all` returns a list (because he's saying that it returns an empty list).

Comment: in the code he has attempted to print it without iterating over it.

Comment: You can just print a list you know.. Also an example with `Selenium` would be nice.

Comment: You are right in fact, dont know why I was thinking you had to iterate over it, probably because ive been doing it by default to access the individual elements.

Comment: Selenium can scrap data? I thought it just automated web tasks like filling out forms.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this should throw up syntax errors:

```
page = requests.g et("https://skinup.gg/"
```

Change it to:

```
page = requests.get("https://skinup.gg/")
```

I suggest using lxml instead of html.parser, it's faster and lighter.

Now, to answer your question,

The div segments with win as class attribute are under the div segment with history class attribute. So *first you search for history* and then search for *win within the obtained list*.

But, when i ran your script and cross checked the page source of the site you linked, there is no div segment with win class attribute.

Could you mention, where you got the *Relevant website code* from?

Comment: I got the relevant code from opening the webpage and using inspector. Thanks for the earlier suggestions I will try them out.

Answer (score 1):

As t.m.adam mentioned , urllib or requests can't get the dynamic page source.
But when you see the page you linked with chrome developer tools, you can see that div win class is generated when round.multiplier >2.

 These are received by 'socketcluster/' which use wss protocol.

so you should use python wss module to acheive your goal.

Comment: So I have to use a different library to get dynamic websites source code? How did you find out thaf the div win class updates when round multiplier is greater than 2? I can't seem to find it using firefox's dev tools. Thanks.

Comment: you can find the js files from that site, then search a word with "history" or "win". and as I know, you have to use a different liarary like web socket client or something else to recieve dynamic datas via wss.